# Typescript: How to use bowser typings?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, bowser

I'm updating an AngularJS project to Typescript using Webpack.

Because we are using `bowser` in our codebase I installed and referenced the related typings.

But still after done this the compiler keeps complaining that the `bowser` name is unknown.

Does someone know how to effectively use the `bowser` typings? It worked out of the box for the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate *.d.ts file (I have one for miscellaneous shims since so many typings are terrible), you need to add this line:

```
declare var bowser: BowserModule.IBowser;
```

For some reason the typing currently doesn't include the actual instantiated object.